Filter Service Account Keys
is there any software that allows you to properly store Service Account keys (GCP in particular, but also for other Cloud Providers),
Which could allow you to filter SA keys by roles and by project to know which account has which rights,
I manage a lot of different SA / SA keys and it's a bit of a mess if I only store them by folder in a password / file manager, knowing that some have rights by folder, others by project, etc.
Thanks in advance :)
Password / File manager, but no visual on account rights

And why do you need all this service account key file. Normally, on a few cases require keys. You can avoid using them most of the time.

Secret Manager is a secure and convenient storage system for API keys, passwords, certificates, and other sensitive data. Please refer to the official GCP Secret Manager documentation for details.
Kindly refer to the document for other Cloud providers also.

Hi @Hexca Please let me know weather provided comment helps you to solve your Issue?

Hello @HemanthKanchumurthy, this doesn't help me :)
